# How to mutate a column with different tempfiles?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'd like to mutate a column with *different* tempfiles. How can I do it, given that `tempfile()` isn't vectorized?
The following code simply returns the same tempfile.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(foo = 1:5)
df |> 
  mutate(my_tmp_file = tempfile())
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>     foo my_tmp_file                                                             
#>   <int> <chr>                                                                   
#> 1     1 /var/folders/6g/tmb5z48550s3dl4dp56dvy780000gp/T//RtmpHag8uI/file5cb067… 
#> 2     2 /var/folders/6g/tmb5z48550s3dl4dp56dvy780000gp/T//RtmpHag8uI/file5cb067…  
#> 3     3 /var/folders/6g/tmb5z48550s3dl4dp56dvy780000gp/T//RtmpHag8uI/file5cb067… 
#> 4     4 /var/folders/6g/tmb5z48550s3dl4dp56dvy780000gp/T//RtmpHag8uI/file5cb067…
#> 5     5 /var/folders/6g/tmb5z48550s3dl4dp56dvy780000gp/T//RtmpHag8uI/file5cb067…
```

I thought I could mutate with `purrr::map()`, supplying `tempfile()` as the function, but `map()` requires also `.x` which I don't have/need, so I get an error of  `argument ".x" is missing, with no default`.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replicate`:

```r
df |>
  mutate(tf = replicate(n(), tempfile()))
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#     foo tf                                                                 
#   <int> <chr>                                                              
# 1     1 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a2818ba128f"
# 2     2 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a2849741e4" 
# 3     3 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a2816206e5c"
# 4     4 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a2831543f8c"
# 5     5 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a2813456146"
```

Or if `foo` is guaranteed-unique, you can use `foo` as part of the name,

```r
df |>
  mutate(tf = paste0(tempfile(), "_", foo))
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#     foo tf                                                                 
#   <int> <chr>                                                              
# 1     1 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a2834c2b5_1"
# 2     2 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a2834c2b5_2"
# 3     3 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a2834c2b5_3"
# 4     4 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a2834c2b5_4"
# 5     5 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a2834c2b5_5"
```

If you really want/need to use `purrr`, then `tempfile()` can still be used, we'll ignore the `.x`:

```r
df |>
  mutate(tf = purrr::map_chr(foo, ~ tempfile()))
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#     foo tf                                                                 
#   <int> <chr>                                                              
# 1     1 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a28487ffb9" 
# 2     2 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a2839cf352e"
# 3     3 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a286e5c5cce"
# 4     4 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a2825b6280" 
# 5     5 "C:\\Users\\r2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp2REMs5\\file3a286a1f9e6"
```